# Why does Laravel throw BladeCompiler Timeout error and how to debug it?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.4

I have an odd error happening sometimes, but can't debug it and I'm not sure how to catch or handle it.

Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 104916440 bytes)
Exception:

```
{
"class": "Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError",
"message": "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 104916440 bytes)",
"code": 0,
"file": "/var/www/vhosts/ebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php:232"
}
```

Any idea how I could handle or catch this so I can find the source of the error?

The code at the line 232 is the following:

```
foreach (token_get_all($value) as $token) {
        $result .= is_array($token) ? $this->parseToken($token) : $token;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you have repeating components that do queries? Try enabling debug bar to check the culprit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.